# Quitar elemento especifico en arrays similares dentro de array

Tags: php

Necesito sacar el estado del siguiente array de array asociativo:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=9)
  'idnovedades' => string '1' (length=1)
  'idGarantias' => string '329' (length=3)
  'numeroOperacion' => string '329' (length=3)
  'saldoAdeudado' => string '10000.00' (length=8)
  'montoGarantia' => string '1000000.05' (length=10)
  'saldoVencido' => string '12132.11' (length=8)
  'diasMora' => string '132131' (length=6)
  'observaciones' => string '321321qawasdadasda' (length=18)
  'estado' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
array (size=9)
  'idnovedades' => string '2' (length=1)
  'idGarantias' => string '329' (length=3)
  'numeroOperacion' => string '329' (length=3)
  'saldoAdeudado' => string '3.29' (length=4)
  'montoGarantia' => string '3.29' (length=4)
  'saldoVencido' => string '2.39' (length=4)
  'diasMora' => string '239' (length=3)
  'observaciones' => string '239assadasd' (length=11)
  'estado' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Para esto usé este código:

```
 foreach ($registros['data'] as $key => $value) {
            unset($registros['data'][$key]['estado']);
       }
       return $registros;
```

Funcionar, funciona, pero quería saber si hay algún metodo PHP que resuelva esto de una forma mas eficiente o si lo dejo así.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra solución podría ser usando [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
array_walk($registros['data'], function(&$data) {
    unset($data['estado']);
});
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/WZHP56637)</kbd>

Comment: Funciona, gracias!!

Comment: Vuelvo, No esta deprecado el pase por referencia?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php . Dice que esta deprecado, pero funciona de todas formas, o estoy viendo mal las cosas?

Comment: @Fer, lo que esta deprecado es realizar la llamada pasando por referencia (`eg: $res = miFn(&$data)`), pero no así la definición de una función indicando que recibe los datos por referencia (`eg: function miFn(&$data) {...}`). Son 2 cosas distintas, una es llamada en ejecución y la otra es por definición.

Comment: Entendido, gracias @Marcos !

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te puede servir la función `array_map` (http://php.net/array_map). Sirve para recorrer los elementos de un array y aplicarles una función a todos ellos. Algo así:

```
$array_nuevo = array_map(function($v) {
    unset($v['estado']);
    return $v;
}, $array_original);
```

Comment: Funciona también! Gracias!